# framework not found FBSDKLoginKit for architecture x86_64

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fbsdk

I'm getting this error

> framework not found FBSDKLoginKit for architecture x86_64

, while building IOS in `react native` project. Any solutions how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try to install the login kit via Podfile :

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'your_app' do
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
end
```